# What to use instead of System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGet in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-7.0, .net-4.7.2

I am trying to convert a codebase from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 7 and I have a few interfaces where I am using WebGet attributes to be later used with WCF endpoints.

```
[System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGet(UriTemplate = "", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
```

I am unsure what to use instead of the WebGet attribute because of the assembly System.ServiceModel.Web seems to be gone in .NET 7.

Any ideas on how to port this functionality to .NET 7?

Comment: The answer depends entirely on how you're porting your WCF project. As you're using `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` that's a sign you're using WCF's (awful) REST-like configuration, in that case you should be targeting ASP.NET Core Web API, and your WCF methods should be converted to ASP.NET Core Web API Controller Actions - or custom endpoints. But you might be using a different technique to port your project, but you haven't given us many details to work with.

Comment: This is not the main way how my WCF service is configured. I have a few routes like this because the clients need to download config files and others from the service.

I am trying to port this WCF service and could not find out how to resolve these missing classes.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me: I'm saying that I don't think you need **any** of those "missing classes" in the first place _at all_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **CoreWCF** Project team has released **CoreWCF**, a port of WCF to the .NET Core platform. It provides a compatible implementation of SOAP, NetTCP, and WSDL. Usage in code is similar to WCF, but updated to use ASP.NET Core as the service host, and to work with .NET Core. This is the first major release of the project, and provides WCF functionality for .NET Core, .NET Framework, and .NET 5+.

This is the version documentation for corewcf：[CoreWCF Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/corewcf)

At the same time, **CoreWCF.WebHttp** in **CoreWCF** I think can solve your problem.

This is an example of **CoreWCF.WebHttp** that I think will help you:[CoreWCF.WebHttp](https://corewcf.github.io/blog/2022/04/13/webhttp)